# Any suggestion for smtp mail server in nodejs?

Tags: smtp, node.js

I googled out quite a few but all are at best alpha versions, so it seems I will have to try an code one. Instead of coding one from scratch I would like to build on existing implementation, but a good one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Were you intending to *only* receive email, or send as well?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

SMTP server - I've used [Simple SMTP](https://github.com/andris9/simplesmtp) in conjunction with [mailparser](https://github.com/andris9/mailparser).  IMHO, these are the best tools on the Internet for building SMTP servers in Node.js.

**UPDATE**: Simple SMTP has been deprecated.  Use [SMTP server](https://github.com/andris9/smtp-server) instead (the successor of the Simple SMTP module).

Comment: Also, I don't like Haraka.  :)

Comment: interesting. Any specific reasons you don't like Haraka? Too complex, or something like that?

Comment: @JasonSmith Yes, pretty much. Haraka is way too heavy for me, and there seems to be a much larger learning curve. The simplicity of [simplesmtp](https://github.com/andris9/simplesmtp) in conjunction with [mailparser](https://github.com/andris9/mailparser) is what sold me on these tools. I built a secure (TLS) mail server that authenticates users from a DB, parses incoming messages, allows users to upload files to the system by simply sending an email to a specific email address, and more - all under 400 lines of code. If you need a feature like SPAM filtering, Haraka might be the way to go.

Comment: Simple smtp looks very promising to me. Just hook into the events generated by the server and handle the incoming mails in the way you need to. I will definitely use it. Thx.

Comment: @tfmontague [smtp-server](https://github.com/andris9/smtp-server) is written by the same author and is the successor to Simple SMTP.

Comment: MailIn server use for receiving mail, parses them.

Answer (score 25):

Haraka: https://github.com/baudehlo/Haraka

Is a full featured mail server in node.js - should do everything that you need.

Answer (score 11):

RFC 2821 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2821) is not too complex, you should be able to flesh out a server in about 300 lines of js.

Comment: By the way, this answer is meant to sound like "give it a try, you can do it" not like "whatever, that's easy." :)

Comment: Well I found [Haraka](https://github.com/baudehlo/Haraka). It seems good but, it needs Mail Delivery Agent to send mails, furthermore my hosting service already provides good anti-spam protection, spf, etc, so I have decided to write a milter for sendmail in Python.

Comment: I 100% agree with the sentiment of this answer. Even if you decide to use a library (which is what I do), writing your own will help you to understand what's going on and is a very valuable exercise. It's not that hard.

Comment: 300 lines of code is not a measure. One can write those 300 lines for several days or even weeks.

Answer (score 9):

Some answers here are quite outdated, so I'd like to offer the lastest.

There are currently three Node SMTP servers (libraries) I know of:

- [Haraka](https://haraka.github.io/) (which has been mentioned and is quite robust/heavy)
- [smtp-server](https://github.com/andris9/smtp-server) (this is the successor to the deprecated Simple SMTP project)
- [smtp-protocol](https://github.com/substack/node-smtp-protocol)

There's also [mailin](http://mailin.io/) which is an SMTP server that receives messages and posts them to some URL for you to process. Mailin uses Python for some optional features.

Comment: Is Haraka for sending or receiving emails?

Comment: @Green Haraka is a mail transfer agent ("MTA"). Whether it's for "sending" or "receiving" really depends on where you are in the transaction. Have a look at [Email_agent_(infrastructure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_agent_(infrastructure)) to get an idea of where an MTA fits in.